# How to throw an exception back in JSON in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Request Mapping -

```
  @RequestMapping("/fetchErrorMessages")
  public @ResponseBody int fetchErrorMessages(@RequestParam("startTime") String startTime,@RequestParam("endTime") String endTime) throws Exception
  {
      if(SanityChecker.checkDateSanity(startTime)&&SanityChecker.checkDateSanity(endTime))
      {
          return 0;
      }
      else
      {
          throw new NotFoundException("Datetime is invalid");
      }
  }
```

If the startTime and endTime are invalid, I want to throw a 500 error but return the exception string in JSON. However, I get a HTML Page instead saying

> **Whitelabel Error Page**
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Dec 20 10:49:37 IST 2017
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Datetime is invalid

I instead wanted to return 500 with a JSON

```
{"error":"Date time format is invalid"}
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you have a custom Exception class `NotFoundException` and its implementations something like this:

```
public class NotFoundException extends Exception {

    private int errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public NotFoundException(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }

    public NotFoundException(String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        super(msg, throwable);
    }

    public NotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public NotFoundException(String message, int errorCode) {
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = message;
    }


    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.errorCode + " : " + this.getErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

Now you want to throw some exception from controller. If you throw a exception then you must catch it from a standard Error Handler class, say for example in spring they provide `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to apply to make a class Standard Error Handler. When it is applied to a class then this spring component (I mean the class you annotated) can catch any exception thrown from controller. But We need to map exception class with proper method. So we defined a method with your exception `NotFoundException` handler something like below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object processValidationError(NotFoundException ex) {
        String result = ex.getErrorMessage();
        System.out.println("###########"+result);
        return ex;
    }
}
```

You want to sent **http status to internal server error(500)**, so here we used `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`. Since you used Spring-boot so you do not need to make a json string except a simple annotation `@ResponseBody` can do that for you automagically.

Comment: I followed everything you had explained for my project and I am getting this as output - `NotFoundException{statusCode=400, message='Invalid mode of payment'}`, however I would like only the JSON part of it.. do you how this can be achieved?

Comment: @a11apurva, In NotFoundException class you see `toString()` method, you should have one more method like `toJSON()` and return a json object.

Answer (score 8):

Create a custom exception.

```
public class SecurityException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7806029002430564887L;

    private String message;

    public SecurityException() {
    }

    public SecurityException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Create a custom response entity.

```
public class SecurityResponse {

    private String error;

    public SecurityResponse() {

    }

    public SecurityResponse(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

}
```

Create a ControllerAdvice with ExceptionHandler for custom exception, it will handle the custom exception, populate and return the custom response as below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(SecurityException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public SecurityResponse handleSecurityException(SecurityException se) {
        SecurityResponse response = new SecurityResponse(se.getMessage());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Throw the custom exception based on your condition.

```
throw new SecurityException("Date time format is invalid");
```

Now run and test you app. E.G. :

[image]

Comment: Why are you even using securityException? this can be perform without securityException class too

Answer (score 2):

you can create `NotFoundException` class with `@ResponseStatus` annotation like below:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
   public NotFoundException() {
   }

   public NotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
   }

}
```

Comment: This does work but I would not recommend this approach. It doesn't give the possibility to show a custom message in case you want one and it isn't secure either because it'll still shows something like "Apache Tomcat/8.0.18"  so people with bad intentions now can search more specific for breaches in your system.

Comment: @GlennVanSchil: you can show an error message through the "message" argument of the exception; furthermore, the name of the exception itself is a message

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in my application:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice {

   @ExceptionHandler(ExecutionRestrictionViolationException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<String> handleExecutionRestrictionViolationException(ExecutionRestrictionViolationException ex) {
     return response("Invalid Query", ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
   }

   private static String createJson(String message, String reason) {
    return "{\"error\" : \"" + message + "\"," +
            "\"reason\" : \"" + reason  + "\"}";
   }

   private static ResponseEntity<String> response(String message,
                                               String reason,
                                               HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    String json = createJson(message, reason);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(json, httpStatus);
   }

}
```

Explanation:

1. You create a controller Advice, mark it with a special annotation and define just like any other bean (in my case it was a java configuration, but it doesn't really matter)
2. For each Exception you would like to handle like this - define a handler that will generate a response in a format you want
3. There is a static method createJson - you can use a different way, it also doesn't matter really.

Now this is only one way to work (its available in more recent spring boot versions) - but there are others:

All the methods I'm aware of (and even more) are listed [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

Comment: If he throws `NotFoundException` then shouldn't your `@ExceptionHandler` class be `@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)` ?

Comment: Yes sure, you're completely right on this. I've just shown a code snippet (the idea) from my application. It should be one method per exception type I believe.

Comment: Looks like I can just send accept headers from client and the response will be in JSON (thanks to Jackson)

Answer (score 1):

Javax has a interface name as ExceptionMapper. Please refer the below code snippet, For every RuntimeException in your application it will map it to a Json Response entity.

```
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper <RuntimeException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(RuntimeException exception) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    errorResponse.setMessage(exception.getMessage);
    if (exception== null) {
        logger.error("Exception Details Not found");            
    } else {
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(errorResponse )
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("trace-id", "1234").build();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a few ways to do this, some more sensible than others depending on your situation.

(Great tutorial here on several options. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-exceptions-json)

My favorite is this one because I want to send back a proper error message and an appropriate http response without creating a superclass or creating helper methods in a utility class or copying boilerplate everywhere.

If you want to inform the caller that the event caused an error (and in proper JSON), use Spring's ResponseStatusException. It gives you access to the httpReponse object so you can also send back a response other than 'ok'.

It wants an exception as one of it's parameters. For one of my scenarios I wanted to inform the caller that they were trying to register a user that already existed. Typically, looking up a user isn't supposed to throw an exception but in this case I created my own exception and I throw it back to the caller in a [ResponseStatusException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html) like so:

```
  @PostMapping("/register")
  public ResponseEntity register(@RequestBody AccountUserDto user) {
    UserDetails userExists = userDetailsService.loadUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

  if (userExists != null) {
      UserExistsException exc = new UserExistsException("Error: Email address " + user.getEmail() +  " is already in use.");
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "User Exists", exc);
  }
....(fall through and create user)
```