# Throwing custom errors as Json when a parameter is invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, error-handling

I am working on an API and need to throw and exception that looks like this

```
"error": "sortBy parameter is invalid"
}
```

if the sort by parameter is not one of my predetermined values,
i have a few parameters to do this for
here is what my controller looks like

```
@GetMapping("/api/posts")

    public ResponseEntity<List<Post>> getPostResponse(@RequestParam String tag, Optional<String> sortBy,
            Optional<String> direction) throws InvalidSortBy {

        RestTemplate postResponseTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        URI postUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("urlHere")
                                          .queryParam("tag", tag)
                                          .queryParamIfPresent("sortBy", sortBy)
                                          .queryParamIfPresent("direction", direction)
                                          .build()
                                          .toUri();

        ResponseEntity<PostResponse> response = postResponseTemplate.getForEntity(postUri, PostResponse.class);
        ResponseEntity<List<Post>> newResponse = responseService.createResponse(response, sortBy, direction);   
    
         return newResponse;

    }
}
```

ive remove the url but it works for sorting the incoming data but i need to validate and throw correct errors, im just really not sure how to do it in the format required, as json, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to handle your exception and resolve it based on error, I would suggest you raise error codes for known application exception and resolve them in your exception handler (either by using @ControllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice), once you have translated error code to respective message send them as json  you can refer below thread for more details on following SO thread

[How to throw an exception back in JSON in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899292/how-to-throw-an-exception-back-in-json-in-spring-boot)

**@ExceptionHandler**

> @ExceptionHandler to tell Spring which of our methods should be
> invoked for a given exception

**@RestControllerAdvice**

> Using `@RestControllerAdvice` which contains @ControllerAdvice to
> register the surrounding class as something each @Controller should be
> aware of, and @ResponseBody to tell Spring to render that method's
> response as JSON